# JQGrid - JQuery loading data with IE9

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have made one `JQgrid` which calls `Ajax` for getting data on loading the page. But in IE9 it is problem that it is not loading data on loading the form but as and when I reload the page then the same process is done and I am able to see the data in grid. Is there any problem with IE9 or in Grid ?It is displaying in all other browsers.

It is displaying blank grid without data.

My grid definition is as below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
               jQuery("#internetusagerecords").jqGrid({
                height:250,
                datatype: 'local',
                colNames:['IP Address','Start Time',
                            <% if (isHttpMacFlowOn){%>
                                'MAC Address',
                            <% } %>
                             'Stop Time','Used Time','Effective Session Time','Downloaded Data','Uploaded Data','Total Transfer'],
                colModel :[ 
                    {name:'ip', index:'ip', sorttype:'text'},
                    {name:'starttime', index:'starttime', sorttype:'int',align:"right"},
                    <% if (isHttpMacFlowOn){ %>
                    {name:'macaddress', index:'macaddress',  sorttype:'text', align:"left"},
                    <% } %>
                    {name:'stoptime', index:'stoptime', sorttype:'int',align:"right"},
                    {name:'usedtime', index:'usedtime',  sorttype:'text', align:"right"},       
                    {name:'effectivesession', index:'effectivesession',sorttype:'date', align:"right"},     
                    {name:'download', index:'download', sorttype:'int',align:"right"},
                    {name:'upload', index:'upload',sorttype:'int',align:"right"},
                    {name:'totaltransfer', index:'totaltransfer',sorttype:'int',align:"right"}],
                pager:jQuery('#internetusagepager'),
                rowNum:10,
                sortname: 'ip',
                autowidth:true,
                sortorder: "asc",
                rowList:[10,20,50,100,200],
                viewrecords: true,
                loadonce:false,
                grouping:true,
                footerrow: true,
                userDataOnFooter: true,
                gridComplete: function call1(){},
                /*
                loadComplete: function(data) {
                    var costsum = jQuery("#records").jqGrid('getCol', 'estimatedcost', true, 'sum');
                    var calldurationsum = jQuery("#records").jqGrid('getCol', 'seconds', true, 'sum');
                    var unitssum = jQuery("#records").jqGrid('getCol', 'units', true, 'sum');
                    jQuery("#records").jqGrid('footerData','set', {starttime: 'Total:', estimatedcost: costsum,seconds: calldurationsum,units: unitssum});
                },
                */
                caption:'Internet Usage Details'
              });
            });
```

Comment: Is there any need for Java Source ?

Comment: i think it is problem of isHttpMacFlowOn  set/unset.

Comment: @PriyankPatel There is not any problem with the isHttpMac because it is displaying in the grid in other browsers.

Comment: Try debugging by putting alert in ready , gridComplete .

Comment: jQuery("#internetusagerecords").jqGrid({ your options...}).trigger('reloadGrid');  try this.

Comment: You wrote that you have problem with *filling* of grid in IE9, but you posted **no code which fill the grid**. Moreover it's not clear why you use `datatype: 'local'` if the data need be loaded per Ajax?

Comment: Maybe he is using the jQuery `.ajax` method to retrieve the data as a separate operation? In any case, I agree we need to see the actual JavaScript code that is retrieving the data and populating the grid, since that is where the problem seems to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there was the problem with the old `JQuery` package. Which is now resolved in the `JQGrid` library.

I have also faced the same problem regarding the `JQuery`'s `JQgird` with IE9 and now it is resolved.

I downloaded the new package and checked with that thing then it resolved my problem with IE9.